# Display prompt with firefox addon sdk

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Is it possible to display a blocking "yes no" confirm dialog to the user using chrome privileges?

Something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

accept nicks answer but read this:

Here's another way to access nsIPromptService. And check that page for more alerts:

```
var {Cu, Ci} = require('chrome');
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm');
var doit = Services.prompt.confirm(null, 'title', 'message');
if (doit) { 
//he clicked yes
}
```

instead of null you can pass in a window object like `Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow(null)` and it becomes modal on that window

benefit of this way is it uses services.jsm so you arent loading nsipromptservice you're just getting a pointer to it, which is preferred way

Comment: This looks like a better solution to me.

Answer (score 1):

I found the [nsIPromptService](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIPromptService), which does exactly what i want:

```
var chrome = require('chrome');
var prompts = chrome.Cc["@mozilla.org/embedcomp/prompt-service;1"].getService(chrome.Ci.nsIPromptService);
var remove = prompts.confirm(null, 'title', 'message');
```

Comment: Is `chrome` a global that's available to all sdk addons? Or does it have to be dev defined?

Comment: Nope, i just didn't use the destructuring assignment. I added the import for completeness.

Comment: Oh cool i didn't you could restructure to `chrome`! Thx for update